# setState not changing value in gridview in flutter

Tags: gridview, flutter, setstate

basically i m updating list value that used in gridview, when i click on gridview card, i m changing color of that card. when i print color value it did changing but in gridview has no effect. Plz suggest me what to do? is my logic approach is wrong ?

```
class FilterDialog extends ModalRoute<void> {

   List<Grades> mGradeList = [];
   List<Styles> mStyleList = [];
   List<Types> mTypeList = [];
   List<Specials> mSpecialList = [];

   FilterDialog(this.mGradeList, this.mStyleList, this.mTypeList, this.mSpecialList);


      @override
      Widget buildPage(
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      ) {
        // This makes sure that text and other content follows the material style
        return Material(
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          // make sure that the overlay content is not cut off
          child: SafeArea(
            child: _buildOverlayContent(context),
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildOverlayContent(BuildContext context) {
        return new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
            child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    titleWidget("Grade"),  
                    gridViewWidget(mGradeList, 3, 2.2),

                    spaceWidget(),
                    titleWidget("Style"),  
                    gridViewWidget(mStyleList, 2, 3.5),

                    spaceWidget(),
                    titleWidget("Type"),  
                    gridViewWidget(mTypeList, 2, 3.5),

                    spaceWidget(),
                    titleWidget("Special"),  
                    gridViewWidget(mSpecialList, 2, 3.5),
                ],
              )
          );
      }

      Widget gridViewWidget(list, int count, double ratio) {
        return GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: count,
          mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
          childAspectRatio: ratio,
          physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: _getTiles(list)
        );
      }

      void _onTileClicked(int index, value, list){
        assert(index != null);
        assert(value != null);
        setState(() {
            list[index].setSelected(!value);
        });
        debugPrint("You tapped on item $index with $value");
      }

      // Get grid tiles
    List<Widget> _getTiles(list) {
      final List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        tiles.add(new GridTile(
              child: new Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 35.0,
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => _onTileClicked(i, list[i]["selected"], list),
                    color: list[i]["selected"] ? backgroundColor : white, //here value not changing
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    child: new Text(
                      list[i]["label"],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
      return tiles;
    }
```

class model:

```
class Grades {
    String label;
    bool selected;

    Grades(this.label, this.selected);

    void setSelected(bool val) {
        this.selected = val;
    }
}
```

some data:

```
var typeList = [{"label": "Crack", "selected": false}, {"label": "Face", "selected": false},
   {"label": "Slab", "selected": false}, {"label": "Multi-pitch", "selected": false} ];
```

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't make your UI within `ModalRoute`. You should move that to a widget

Comment: @RémiRousselet  i get this point, but is there any way with ModalRoute? bcz the requirement is to make filterview in transparent full screen dialog.

Comment: `_buildOverlayContent` should be passed to the constructor instead of being a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class has to extend **StatefulWidget** along with it having a **State** widget in order for you to use the **setState()** method. For example:

```
class FilterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterWidgetState createState() => _FilterWidgetState();
}

class _FilterWidgetState extends State<FilterWidget> {
    //lists here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //build stuff here with setState() being used
  }
}
```

[You can find more information here from the official docs.](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/#step-1)

Comment: setState is working fine..  i can't use StatefulWidget becase its dialog modal class, and i m getting updated value everytime, its just has no effect on gridview

Comment: The logic within setState will change the values but the point of setState is to [notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed.](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html). As your Widget isn't Stateful or extend State then the setState() method will not work. Can I ask why you're extending the ModalRoute class?

Comment: because filterview should be in transperent dialog. thats why i m using ModalRoute class. is there any other way to make transperent dialog with statfulwidget.

Comment: You can use the **Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8)** (with whatever value you want) or **Colors.transparent** for the color prop of a Scaffold or Material widget to get a transparent/glass like effect. Maybe give that a go?

Comment: it work with StatefulWidget, but not working with ModalRoute. Thanks for opening my eye. now only problem remain is to make page transparent.. i guess its not possible without ModalRoute.

Comment: Keep it as a StatefulWidget and then use it as the builder prop for the showDialog method. As long as your dialog uses the Material or Scaffold widget as it's main body widget, you can then use the color properties I mentioned earlier to change the transparency of the dialog's background.

Comment: Its not working.. i tried to set background for Scaffold but it not work.. if you find any solution, plz do mention here..

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget _buildOverlayContent(BuildContext context) {
gridViewWidget(mTypeList, 2, 3.5)

List<Widget> _getTiles(list) {
onPressed: () => _onTileClicked(i, list[i]["selected"], list),

final typeList = [{"label": "Crack", "selected": false}, {"label": "Face", "selected": false},
   {"label": "Slab", "selected": false}, {"label": "Multi-pitch", "selected": false}
```

Do you intent to use typeList as a global state?
I think the variable should not have a final modifier.

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour

> If you never intend to change a variable, use final or const, either
>   instead of var or in addition to a type. A final variable can be set
>   only once; a const variable is a compile-time constant. (Const
>   variables are implicitly final.) A final top-level or class variable
>   is initialized the first time it’s used.

I am basing my answer on the fact that you are accessing the `list[i]["selected"]` as a map while you define `Grades` as a object.

Comment: Thanks.. i'll keep in mind.. but this is not helping with my question.

Comment: The answer could had been two choices. I guess the wrong choice. The other problem is the stateful widget. Oh well. 50/50 chance

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. My solution is to reconstruct the object you want to change in GridView. Do not update the item in list but reconstruct the list and update the item as you like. Maybe it work.

I guess that if the point of list is not changed, the GridView that includes it will not be changed.