# UI not updating on setState. But does after i shuffle the list i want to display (confused). Not solved

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I'm writing a word game with Flutter + Dart.

I have 2 rows that should display X amount of widgets in the form of letter pieces. The first row is empty, the second has letters in it, when i press a row 2 letter i want the first row pieces to include this letter.

Imagine a word game, with letters ready to be tapped to fill out the empty boxes to create the correct word.

I have 3 classes, main, LetterPiece, EmptyLetterPiece.
Including some variables such as letter. EmptyLetterPiece has the default letter = ''; And will on button press be set to a letter.

Main has a statefulwidget, the others are Statelesswidgets.

I create new lists for both LetterPiece and EmptyLetterPiece objects.
Length based on a word i choose.

MY PROBLEM:

"A" is the test value i assign when letter is pressed, they get the values when i print them out, but the UI is not updating. UNLESS i do -> emptyPieces.shuffle(); every time in the generate method.

Then the objects in emptyPieces display "A".

I don't want to shuffle every time i setState, but that makes the UI update, versus if i dont shuffle the UI won't update!

Read on.

My main class has a Statefulwidget to update the ui.

I have also tried to add a Statefulwidget to the other classes but with no success.

I took a look on this post -> [Flutter setState changing, but not rerendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920963/flutter-setstate-changing-but-not-rerendering) <-
but with no success.

```
//MY BUILD METHOD

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              stops: [0.3, 1],
              colors: [
            Color(firstColor),
            Color(secondColor)
          ])
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(word1, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: textScale, color: Colors.white),),
            generateEmptyPiecesRow(), // <--- 
            generateLetterPiecesRow() // <---
          ],
        ),
    );
  }

//THE TWO GENERATE METHODS.

Widget generateEmptyPiecesRow(){
    if(emptyPieces.length < word2.length) {
      for (int i = 0; i < word2.length; i++) {
        emptyPieces.add(new EmptyLetterPiece(pieceTextScale, 5, 50));
        print("Added. $i");
      }
      emptyPieces.shuffle();
    }
    //emptyPieces.shuffle(); <--- WORKS IF I PUT THIS HERE, UI UPDATES ONLY IF I SHUFFLE THE PIECES BEFORE RETURNING THEM WITH THE ROW. <---
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: emptyPieces);
  }

  Widget generateLetterPiecesRow(){
    if(letterPieces.length < word2.length) {
      for (int i = 0; i < word2.length; i++) {
        letterPieces.add(new LetterPiece(
            word2.substring(i, i + 1).toUpperCase(), pieceTextScale, 15,
            addLetter, removeLetter));
      }
      letterPieces.shuffle();
    }

    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: letterPieces);
  }

//setState methods

addLetter(){
    setState(() {
      emptyPieces[getPiecePos()].setLetter("A");
      increasePiecePos();
    });
  }

  removeLetter(){
    setState(() {
      emptyPieces[getPiecePos()].removeLetter();
      decreasePiecePos();
    });
  }
```

```
// EDIT: THIS IS THE EmptyLetterPiece class build method, LetterPiece has the same structure too.

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(_padding),
            width: _pieceScale,
            height: _pieceScale,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(_letter, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), textScaleFactor: _textScale),
            )
        );
  }
```

I expected the view to update, but it only did so if i first shuffled the list i returned to the view, i don't want the list to update with a shuffle.
I'm clueless as to why it works when i shuffle, and not otherwise. Am I missing something obvious? I'm fairly new to Flutter.

Thanks for your time, if I was unclear please tell me and I try update the question.

Comment: Bring up my post

Answer (score 0):

The view will be updated when you call SetState within the widget you want refreshed. Child widgets will also be refreshed. If you don't want to refresh the widget itself or its child widgets, there are other ways to achieve that.

Comment: I thank you for the information. But I'm not sure you are providing a solution.

Comment: My problem is that the UI only updates if I shuffle the list before i return the Row that is used in my Build method. I don't see the correlation between shuffling my list and because of that see an updated UI. The UI should update otherwise too. It makes me a little confused..

Comment: It would be helpful to break down your problem into a smaller piece of code that can be copied, pasted and compiled quickly.